# ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 300 while Y.shape[1] == 100

Tags: python, scikit-learn, chatbot, chatterbot

I am working on Telegram chatbot  using `chatterbot` package.When I am running my chatbot,sometime it goes very well by responding to my question but after 2-3 question it give me below error :

[image]

When I back tracked the issue, it is failing at this point in my code :

```
def get_best_thread(self, question, tag_name):
        """ Returns id of the most similar thread for the question.
            The search is performed across the threads with a given tag.
        """
        thread_ids, thread_embeddings = self.__load_embeddings_by_tag(tag_name)

        question_vec = question_to_vec(question, self.word_embeddings, self.embeddings_dim)
        best_thread = pairwise_distances_argmin(
            X=question_vec.reshape(1, self.embeddings_dim),
            Y=thread_embeddings,
            metric='cosine'
        )
        return thread_ids[best_thread][0]
```

I am not able to get the issue.However sometime is worked well without any error but most of the time i get this error.

Comment: obviously `self.embeddings_dim`  does not always match the dimensions of `thread_embeddings`

Comment: Then what should i do to resolve this issue.

Comment: it depends: for example you can truncate both data to have the min of both, but I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Why should these match in the first place and is this a correct assumption. That is where I would start